# Arrow not loading on JS Slider [bxslider]

Tags: javascript, bxslider

I followed the link to for bxslider. However , the arrow of my bxslider does not appear instead the text next and previous appear only.

[image]

I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692848/no-arrow-on-images-when-using-bxslider/33227800#33227800) and have checked the the image is present.

I tried using the following example :

```
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="1.jpg"  /></li>
  <li><img src="2.jpg"  /></li>
</ul>


$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  mode: 'fade',
});
```

Any advice? Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We need code to see what's wrong. I know how to solve your issue, but I need you to give me enough information to narrow it down to specifics. With what you've posted, I would have to post several times in order to eliminate the possibilities. So post a [mcve].

Comment: Put this in the `<head>` before any `<script>`----  ----------------------     --------------------------------------------------------------                             `<link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.css' rel='stylesheet'>`